# how to include tikz figure in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

While copy-pasting the following code from my article to one of the frames in my beamer presentation (along with all the packages), I get 11 errors that are mostly "undefined control sequence" and "missing number, treated as zero". 
Could you explain what is wrong and what additional packages I may have to include in the preamble?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\title{HH Decisions}
\author{Abhimanyu Arora}
\institute{Doctoral workshop}
\date{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Results (contd.)}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title=Share of expenditure,
xlabel={$z$},
ylabel={$S(z)$},
]
\addplot [blue,domain=0:10]{(2*(0.45+x*0.55))/(2*(0.45+x*0.55)+0.55+x*0.45)};
\addplot [red,domain=0:10]{(2*(0.1+x*0.9))/(2*(0.1+x*0.9)+0.9+x*0.1)};
\legend{Case 1, Case 2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\floatfoot{Case 1:$\alpha_W=\beta_H=0.55=1-\alpha_H=1-\beta_W$, Case 2:$\alpha_W=\beta_H=0.9=1-\alpha_H=1-\beta_W$}
\label{fig:share}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: It will be very difficult to explain what is wrong and tell you any additional packages without seeing what is in your preamble currently... please post a complete document, starting at `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: Where does `\floatfoot` come from? Which package defines it? If it is a user command, are you including the definition in your preamble?

Comment: Thank you @darthbith. I have editted the code to include the preamble. The article seems to compile fine but not the presentation

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Thanks, have editted to include the preamble. But as you might notice, there are errors

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora Thanks for providing the example code. I provided an answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `floatrow` package is not compatible with `beamer`; don't load this package with the `beamer` document class; in this case, you can't use `\floatfoot`, but you can use `\caption` instead or just a simple paragraph of text:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\title{HH Decisions}
\author{Abhimanyu Arora}
\institute{Doctoral workshop}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Results (contd.)}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  title=Share of expenditure,
  xlabel={$z$},
  ylabel={$S(z)$},
  height=6cm
]
\addplot [blue,domain=0:10]{(2*(0.45+x*0.55))/(2*(0.45+x*0.55)+0.55+x*0.45)};
\addplot [red,domain=0:10]{(2*(0.1+x*0.9))/(2*(0.1+x*0.9)+0.9+x*0.1)};
\legend{Case 1, Case 2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Case 1:$\alpha_W=\beta_H=0.55=1-\alpha_H=1-\beta_W$, Case 2:$\alpha_W=\beta_H=0.9=1-\alpha_H=1-\beta_W$}
\label{fig:share}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Results (contd.)}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  title=Share of expenditure,
  xlabel={$z$},
  ylabel={$S(z)$},
  height=6cm
]
\addplot [blue,domain=0:10]{(2*(0.45+x*0.55))/(2*(0.45+x*0.55)+0.55+x*0.45)};
\addplot [red,domain=0:10]{(2*(0.1+x*0.9))/(2*(0.1+x*0.9)+0.9+x*0.1)};
\legend{Case 1, Case 2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\par
Case 1:$\alpha_W=\beta_H=0.55=1-\alpha_H=1-\beta_W$, Case 2:$\alpha_W=\beta_H=0.9=1-\alpha_H=1-\beta_W$
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]